Possible to design such a toroidal induction motor?
Coils are wound as on a plastic toroidal ring as a retaining former and placed inside two axially split halves of a toroidal stator. These are joined making a leak tight  weld and later filled with transformer oil from an opening provided and  closed to ensure no contact between the tori to function   as a stator/rotor combination.
Also suppose several pairs of permanent magnets are placed around the stationary outer torus thus attempting  here to make a crude toroidal induction motor.
Under proper start conditions can the inner wound torus be made to rotate inside the outer one,  when outer magnetic the lines are cut by inner coils by Faraday's EM  induction Law ?
Thanks for all suggestions and comments to realize  such an enclosed toroidal stator/moving rotor pair.

